# How can i fill data of a row into another sheet just by clicking any cell of the data table

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 sheets in an Excel workbook.
The first one contains a data table named "details", regarding details of students. The second sheet contains several formulated cells with `Vlookup` formula which looks for vlaues in the first sheet.
How can I auto fill all the `Vlookup` cells in sheet 2, for a row from sheet 1, just by clicking on any cell of name column or order column from the first sheet?
E.g. my first sheet has these columns

| order | student name | DOB | cast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Josheph | 15/02/2017 | Christian |
| 2 | Iliyas | 23/05/2012 | Muslim |

I want to auto fill formulated (`Vlookup`) cells of the sheet 2, either by clicking `"Joseph"` or in the order column on `"number 1"`.

Comment: Could you please specify what you are trying to do? Do you have multiple columns that you want to extract (i.e, drag vlookup to the right and adjust the column reference)? Do you have multiple rows you are trying to extract? What is the formula you tried so far and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Yes, i have multiple rows and columns as found in any data table. All column contain various type of data and a specific row belongs to a specific person. I have a custom form (not a user form) which i prepared on second sheet by using Vlookup formula for different cells. All i want to do is, if i click on the name of any person in first sheet data table named as "details" the regarding details of that row should automatically fill in the form (not a user form) in sheet 2. The common Vlookup formula in sheet 2 is =Vlookup($Q$5,sheet1!details,column number,0) Q 5 is a drop down list in sheet 2

Comment: The drop down list contain values from order column from sheet1